# C# Extract bitmap/windows logo from basebrd.dll

Tags: c#, dll, resources

I would like to extract the bitmap that is present on default windows C:\Windows\Branding\Basebrd\basebrd.dll so I can use it on a picturebox or whatever. - AT RUNTIME

Is it possible to archive this? have anyone do so?

I see the resources are there if I load the file with Resource Hacker or Resource Explorer tools, but I am not sure how those can be referenced or extracted from within C# app.

Regards

Comment: Automate the mentioned tools from c#? Atleast ResourceHacker should have usable commandline parameters for this.

Comment: Well, no, the idea is not to depend on those tools, otherwise the app will need to ship and relay on those.

Comment: maybe this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805080/how-do-you-retrieve-an-embedded-image-from-a-dll-for-wpf-image-control

Comment: Tried that but got error - PE image does not have metadata. - so looks like the DLL doesn't have that metadata the app expects.

Comment: The solutions in the link are for assemblies with resx resources. You have an unmanaged dll not an assembly. You may walk your way from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-resources) with using the Windows APIs for that and trying to pinvoke on them. You need multiple. Or rather hope someone already did just that and show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, so I'm sharing the solution

```
var ID = 123;
var FilePath = @"C:\Windows\Branding\Basebrd\basebrd.dll";
IntPtr hMod = LoadLibraryEx(FilePath, IntPtr.Zero, 2); //LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 2
IntPtr hRes = FindResource(hMod, ID, 2); // RT_BITMAP = 0x00000002;
IntPtr hBitmap = LoadBitmap(hMod, new IntPtr(123));
FreeLibrary(hMod);
Bitmap bmp = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
bmp.Save(@"C:\1\img2.bmp");
```